# PHP: How to check if file is complete

Tags: php

I would like to generate a csv using PHP but I want to download the file later using file_get_contents when it is complete. Is there a way to check if a file is already complete?

Comment: You could write a database entry when generating the file completes and only download files from / through the database.

Comment: If you want to trigger it with a button is file_exists() an option?

Comment: Without describing the issue in detail and showing code and how you do it, it is not possible to give you a concrete answer. When you generate a file, you don't need to download it because it's already on the server I guess. As PHP does not work async by default, the file is just ready when `file_get_contents()` finished. Your question is unclear.